# Two applications listening on the same port

Tags: networking, port, application

Wat happens if two applications try to listen to the same port?

Comment: The right answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14388706/632951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one that binds to the port will get an error saying something else is already listening on the port.

Comment: Does the program check for itself if some other program is listening to the port?

Comment: The operating system does the check.

Answer (score 5):

Unless they are spawned via [tcpmux](http://blog.postmaster.gr/2010/12/20/tcpmux-a-mostly-overlooked-tcp-service/), the first application binds to the port and listens for connections to it, while the second one cannot bind and cannot listen.

Comment: What is it that prevents the application from binding to the port?

Comment: When your application makes the relevant system call to "grab" the port, the operating system will "inform" it (via a relevant error code) that it is already taken.