What happens when multiple customers share same public IP
What if the destination IP and port of different customers sharing the same public IP are the same too, and the source port and source IP are the same as well? How will ISP router differentiate then?
Customer A:
Private IP: 192.168.29.5:1234
Public IP: 205.0.113.5:1234
Customer B:
Private IP: 192.168.30.102:1234
Public IP: 205.0.113.5:1234
The same public IP address to multiple customers is rare but not impossible. And after that, even the same source port is more rare, but I am curious to know how communication will happen then?
At ISP’s router implementing carrier-grade NAT takes place, and it assigns a different port, but how will it differentiate in this case amongst customer A and customer B?

Do you assume that this works differently with CGNAT than it does with individual customers' local NAT?

No, I know that when customer ip and port reaches CGNAT it is public ip of customer not private ip, and public ip can be same for multiple customers though rare.

That wasn't really the point though. The point was that even if you remove CGNAT, each individual customer's NAT already has the same issue: one public IP & multiple devices which may want to use the same port. It is not new to CGNAT.

NAT won't use the same source port for different internal IPs. I already explained exactly that in the comment you put on answer I made to an old question.
https://serverfault.com/a/1074629/29373

The NAT device also assigns different outbound ports, and those are NOT the same between different internal clients.


Private IP to Public IP is done by individual’s access point (home router) so then how the isp router which performs NAT come to know about private IP of customers?

That's not CG NAT, that's double NAT. It also doesn't matter. If a customer has a NAT router, and is on a CG NAT ISP, the ISP doesn't need to know about the internal IPs of the customer, just the source port coming off the customer's router. The customer's router has its own NAT/PAT table, that the ISP NAT does not need to know about.
